# Differential equation trick?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem solving the following D.E: $y'=y^2 (t+e^t)$.
The solution involves doing
$(y')/(y^2) = (-1/y)'$

My question is simply why. How does one note / come to this?

Edit: nevermind, soved. Using the quoticient rule it follows trivially.

Comment: Actually it's $(1/y)'=-y'/y^2$ (with a minus sign). And it's just the chain rule, either you notice it or you don't, I guess... (But you could always use the usual trick of “separating the variables”, $\int dy/y^2 = \int (t+e^t) dt$.)

Comment: You now asked three questions on this site, and you recieved answers to all three of them. This site works in a way that when you get an answer that is what you were looking for, you accept the best answer - or if not, then explain what is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'=y^2(t+e^t)\to \frac{dy}{dt}=y^2(t+e^t)\to dy=y^2(t+e^t)dt\to\frac{dy}{y^2}=(t+e^t)dt\to$$$$\int\frac{dy}{y^2}=\int(t+e^t)dt\to-\frac{1}{y}-C=\frac{t^2}{2}+e^t\to y=-\frac{1}{\frac{t^2}{2}+e^t+C}$$